# Expand a complex function in a series

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to expand complex function $f(z) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{1-z}}}{e^z - 1}$ in series in the neighborhood of $z_0 = 1$ to find order of the pole.

We can make replacement $\xi = z - 1$ and expand function $f(\xi) = \frac{e^{1/\xi}}{ee^{\xi} - 1}$ in neighborhood of $\xi_0 = 0$. We expand the numerator and denominator of that function:
$$f(\xi) = \frac{1 + \frac{1}{\xi} + \frac{1}{2!\xi^2} + \frac{1}{3!\xi^3} + ...}{e(1 + \xi + \frac{\xi^2}{2!} + \frac{\xi^3}{3!} + ..) - 1}$$
But i don't know how to divide that. I would be very grateful if you would help me.

Comment: Hints: What kind of singularity does $e^{-1/\xi}$ have at $\xi = 0$?  Does $1/(e^z-1)$ have a singularity at $z=1$?

Comment: You want to say that $1/(e^z-1)$ does not necessarily lay out, but enough to arrange e^{-1/\xi}?

Comment: Yes, $1/(e^z-1)$ is holomorphic near $z=1$, so the type of singularity of $e^{1/(1-z)}/(e^z-1)$ is the same as the type of singularity of $e^{1/(1-z)}$.

Comment: But If I want to find residue in point z = 1, Do I expand $1/(e^z-1)$ near $z = 1$ or I should expand $e^{-1/\xi}$ and take the value of the function $1/(e^z-1)$ in point $z = 1$ ?

Comment: If you want to find the residue then yes, you need to expand $1/(e^z-1)$ as well.  I thought your question was only about the order of the pole, though?

Comment: My question was about expand $f(\xi) = \frac{e^{1/\xi}}{ee^{\xi} - 1}$ near $\xi_0 = 0$, because if it is known that we can get the order of the pole and coefficient $c_{-1} = Res(f(\xi), 0)$

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=res%28exp%281%2F%281-z%29%29%2F%28exp%28z%29-1%29+%3B+1%29&a=%2aC.res-_%2aComplexAnalysisWord-) doesn't give a result either, so I dare say it is not easy to compute the residue.

The problem is that $f$ does not have a pole in $1$, it has an essential singularity there arising from the numerator's essential singularity, and the other part, $\dfrac{1}{e^z-1}$ has a Taylor expansion with infinitely many nonzero terms. Using the substitution $\xi = z-1$ to ease notation, we can expand

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{e^{1+\xi}-1} &= \frac{1}{e^{1+\xi}}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - e^{-(1+\xi)}}\\
&= e^{-(1+\xi)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k(1+\xi)}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k(1+\xi)}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^mk^m}{m!}\xi^m\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^m}{e^k}\right)\xi^m.
\end{align}$$

Multiplying with the expansion $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\xi^{-n}$ of $e^{-1/\xi}$, we obtain the result

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(f;1\right) = - \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!(m+1)!}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^m}{e^k},$$

which doesn't look like a nice series to evaluate.

The residues of $f$ in the poles $2k\pi i,\; k\in \mathbb{Z}$, are of course easy to compute, they are $e^{1/(1-2k\pi i)}$.